# How to add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS in Eclipse with G++ MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

I'm trying to implement this example process enumerator program [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx)

I am getting numerous errors for unresolved symbols, including

```
undefined reference to `EnumProcessModules@16'
```

MSDN seems to have anticipated these issues and included some instructions in the comments, but I am unfamiliar with what they mean and how to implement them. Unfortunately, the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930730.aspx) on TARGETLIBS is not very specific.

```
// To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS
// and compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1
```

How do I add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS? I've downloaded the Windows SDK and know the path to Psapi.lib on my computer (I actually seem to have 4 copies of it in the SDK folders, for different processor architectures). I also have a copy of psapi.a in my MinGW/lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

MinGW uses *.a files instead of *.lib files.

The equivalent of `"psapi.lib"` is `"libpsapi.a"`

This file should be in MinGW directory `"MinGW\lib\libpsapi.a"`

Right-click on project name. Go to:
C/C++ Build -> Settings
Add to Library

Your settings should look like the picture below. On my computer MinGW library is installed on `"c:\MinGW\lib"` but you may have a different location.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I checked in my MinGW\lib folder and I do have "libpsapi.a" in there as well. So, I'm not sure why it's still not finding the library. I tried updating the include statement from #include <psapi.h> to #include <libpsapi.a> but am getting an error on the new include statement: fatal error: : No such file or directory. (I am very new to C++ as you can probably see!)

Comment: No, it's `#include <psapi.h>` in *.cpp file. That's for the compiler, don't touch that. Separately, you have add the library, that's for the linker. I added a picture for you.