# Undefined Reference GetProcessImageFileName C++

Tags: c++, windows, process

Trying to get the full path of the executable from a pid. It fails to compile no matter what I tried. g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
string getProcessName(unsigned long pid)
{
    string name = "";
    TCHAR processPath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    DWORD len = MAX_PATH;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid );
    int rc = GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, processPath, len);
    if(rc > 0)
    {
//      GET STRING HERE
    }
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return name;
}
```

output:

```
..\src\Test.cpp:15:61: error: 'GetProcessImageFileName' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: You shouldn't keep editing your question after you got answer(s). Your original question only mentioned your compilation error. And BTW I don't see how the same code (that failed to compile) even got to the linker stage (to produce linker errors). Please post a new question with all the relevant details for the linker issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [`GetProcessImageFileName` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamea),
It is declared in the header **psapi.h**.

Therefore you need to add:

```
#include <psapi.h>
```

**Side notes:**

1. `using namespace std;` is **not** recommended. See: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
2. The error in your question body is a compilation error. In your title you mentioned *Undefined Reference* which is usually a linker error.
3. After you solve the compilation error, you will need to link with the library that contains the implementation for `GetProcessImageFileName`. On MSVC these are either `Psapi.lib` or `Kernel32.lib` depending on your OS. See the documentation link above. I am not sure what you should use for MinGW.

---

**Edit:**
As mentioned in the comment below: the equivalent for `Psapi.lib` for MinGW is `libpsapi.a`.
See: [How to add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS in Eclipse with G++ MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257231/how-to-add-psapi-lib-to-targetlibs-in-eclipse-with-g-mingw/48257640#48257640).

Comment: no effect compile error

Comment: Are you sure you still get the same compilation error after you add the missing #include ? Or is it a linker error now ?

Comment: yes I had to add someone's fix to add libs to eclipse from mingw in order to fix it. then it outputed an invalid path like \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Users\jredfox\Documents\dev\OpenTerminal-natives\Debug\ instead of an actual path

Comment: I fixed it by linking psapi from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48257640/8477015

Answer (score 0):

It's a linking error between eclipse and mingw . The awnser was found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48257640/8477015

And I changed my code to a working one below

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

string getProcessName(unsigned long pid)
{
    string name = "";
    HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    TCHAR filename[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameEx(phandle, NULL, filename, MAX_PATH);
    CloseHandle(phandle);
    return string(filename);
}
```